# Which component of the Android protocol stack performs cellular encryption?

Tags: encryption, sim-card, cellular-radio

I understand that the SIM Card plays a significant role in generating keys for the encryption and decryption of cellular traffic, but are these keys passed to the Android architecture so that it can use them?
Or does the actual encryption take place on the SIM Card?